# Using Automator services (Quick action) with Office 365

Tags: applescript, automator

I've tried and searched a lot of time now but I can't get my services running under Office 365 (e.g. Word) If I right click and look under "Services" (I hope it's called that I have a german version) my Scripts don't appear there.[image: right click menu]

If I look in the menu they are checked but don't appear

[image]

I wrote the Rainbow hotkey Service. It's just a little tool to copy telephone numbers to clipboard

I hope someone can help me out.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Services (Quick Actions) only appear in the menu if the settings at the very top of the Automator workflow window are set correctly.

You should make sure that "Workflow receives **Text** in **Any Application**" (In fact, you can even specify phone numbers.)

Comment: I will look into that, but I‘m pretty shure I‘ve done it that way